# apt-get update: 404 Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade

I have been trying to update kali linux 202 and this is the error am getting:

```
cimi@kali:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:2 http://old.kali.org/kali moto InRelease                             
Ign:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
Err:4 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
```

Answer (score 2):

The repository http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 simply doesn't exist.
See http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/ for a list of available repos from user strycore.

Remove this repo from your sources (either in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or it's a file in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) and run `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: @cimi please remember to accept this answer with the tick-mark in its left corner, to show that it helped you most

Answer (score -2):

You have installed an Ubuntu key on kali Linux due to which it is unable to read so we are going to replace that key with kali Linux key so which enables our system to understand it.

first gain super-user access by typing `sudo -i`, after that `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and search for

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./
```

I found that in `lutris.list.` To find you can simply enter `cat <name of file>`, once you found that you need to replace it with:

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_Testing ./
```

you can use any text editor for that such as nano, leafpad, vi, etc...

for eg:- `leafpad lutris.list`, now save it and you are done; Now apt-update should work